# Azure Account Free Trial Subscription Disabled How To Activate It Again

Tags: azure

I am new to Azute,I have created a free trail subscription but now it is showing disabled not sure how to reactivate it.Attached screenshot is provided.Anyone can help.

[image]

Comment: You need to [upgrade your subscription](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cost-management-billing/manage/subscription-disabled#:~:text=your%20subscription%20reactivated.-,Your%20credit%20is%20expired,days%2C%20Azure%20disables%20your%20subscription.)

Comment: Open a support ticket.

Answer (score 0):

There may be many factors for a subscription to be disabled. The most common reason is "**Your credit is expired**".

The [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cost-management-billing/manage/subscription-disabled#:%7E:text=your%20subscription%20reactivated.-,Your%20credit%20is%20expired,days%2C%20Azure%20disables%20your%20subscription.) lists several reasons and solutions. You can reactivate the disabled subscription according to the instructions in the official document.

Comment: If the posted answer solves your problem, you can accept it to end the thread.  You only need to click the checkmark next to the answer to switch the gray to filled. Thanks.